# Bootstrap hover size not the same

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How can I make the hover to be equal in size despite the line difference in the paragraph? As of now the size of my hover in 'content' class is different since my p.../p in the second and third card is different in the first and fourth card. Is there a way to make my hover size to be equal in all cards? Please see below codes. Thank you

```
.card .content {
        width: 100%;
        background: #fff;
        opacity: 0.65;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -60%;
        margin-left: -4px;
        transition: all ease 0.5s;
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-shadow: 0px -3px 4px rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.09)
        
    }

    .card .content .category {
        font-size: 17px;
        font-weight: 600
    }

    .card .content .price {
        font-size: 17px;
        font-weight: 500;
        color: #0d6efd
    }

    .card .content p {
        font-weight: 500;
        font-size: 12px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .card:hover .content {
        bottom: 0%
    }

    .buttons button {
        border-radius: 1px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        transition: all ease 0.3s
    }

    .content {
        padding: 10px
    }

    hr {
        border: 0;
        height: 1px;
        width: 60%;
        position: relative;
        margin: 15px auto;
    }

    .d-flex {
        font-weight: 500;
        font-size: 12px;
        margin: 15px auto;
    }

    .fa-play-circle {
        padding-right: 4px;
        padding-top: 3px;
    }

<body>
<div id="image">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="image-column col-lg-3 col-md-6">
            <div class="card h-100 p-1 card-container">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h3>GABEL LOFFEL</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="card-img-wrapper ">
                    <img src="assets\image_1.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="content">
                        <hr>
                        <p>Get out your <br> Lederhosen!</p>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center"> <i class="far fa-play-circle"></i> More </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="image-column col-lg-3 col-md-6">
            <div class="card h-100 p-1 card-container">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h3>GARY GARI</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="card-img-wrapper ">
                    <img src="assets\image_2.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="content">
                        <hr>
                        <p>The delicious <br> headquarters for all <br> your ginger related <br> needs!</p>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center"> <i class="far fa-play-circle"></i> More </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="image-column col-lg-3 col-md-6">
            <div class="card h-100 p-1 card-container">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h3>IL PIATTO</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="card-img-wrapper ">
                    <img src="assets\image_3.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="content">
                        <hr>
                        <p>Got wild finicky kids? <br> Head for Il Piatto for <br> kid-friendly Italian <br> Fun!</p>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center"> <i class="far fa-play-circle"></i> More </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="image-column col-lg-3 col-md-6">
            <div class="card h-100 p-1 card-container">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h3>PIERRE PLATTERS</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="card-img-wrapper ">
                    <img src="assets\image_4.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="content">
                        <hr>
                        <p>Smart talks, Smart <br> eats!</p>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center"> <i class="far fa-play-circle"></i> More </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

enclosed your `<p></P>` in `content` class inside a `div` give one custom class `para` and other bootstrap flex classes to justify and align center

and given `css` to `.content`

`height: 280px !important;`

and given `css` to `.content .para`

`.content .para{ height: 100px !important; }`

```css
.card .content {
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 0.65;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -60%;
  margin-left: -4px;
  transition: all ease 0.5s;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px -3px 4px rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.09)
}

.card .content .category {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 600
}

.card .content .price {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #0d6efd
}

.card .content p {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}

.card:hover .content {
  bottom: 0%
}

.buttons button {
  border-radius: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  transition: all ease 0.3s
}

.content {
  height: 280px !important;
  padding: 10px;
}

.content .para {
  height: 100px !important;
}

hr {
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  width: 60%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 15px auto;
}

.d-flex {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 15px auto;
}

.fa-play-circle {
  padding-right: 4px;
  padding-top: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="image">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="image-column col-lg-3 col-md-6">
      <div class="card h-100 p-1 card-container">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h3>GABEL LOFFEL</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-img-wrapper ">
          <img src="images/2.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
          <div class="content">
            <hr>
            <div class="para d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
              <p>Get out your <br> Lederhosen!</p>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center"> <i class="far fa-play-circle"></i> More </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="image-column col-lg-3 col-md-6">
      <div class="card h-100 p-1 card-container">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h3>GARY GARI</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-img-wrapper ">
          <img src="images/3.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
          <div class="content">
            <hr>
            <div class="para d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
              <p>The delicious <br> headquarters for all <br> your ginger related <br> needs!</p>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center"> <i class="far fa-play-circle"></i> More </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-column col-lg-3 col-md-6">
      <div class="card h-100 p-1 card-container">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h3>IL PIATTO</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-img-wrapper ">
          <img src="images/4.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
          <div class="content">
            <hr>
            <div class="para d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
              <p>Got wild finicky kids? <br> Head for Il Piatto for <br> kid-friendly Italian <br> Fun!
              </p>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center"> <i class="far fa-play-circle"></i> More </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-column col-lg-3 col-md-6">
      <div class="card h-100 p-1 card-container">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h3>PIERRE PLATTERS</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-img-wrapper ">
          <img src="images/2.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
          <div class="content">
            <hr>
            <div class="para d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
              <p>Smart talks, Smart <br> eats!</p>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center"> <i class="far fa-play-circle"></i> More </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Try this code in browser to see

Comment: Thank you Omer for the explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

enclosed your `<p></P>` in `content` class inside a `div` give one custom class `para` and other bootstrap flex classes to justify and align center

and given `css` to `.content`

`height: 280px !important;`

and given `css` to `.content .para`

`.content .para{ height: 100px !important; }`

and in card `img` used class `img-fluid`

```css
.card .content {
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 0.65;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -60%;
  margin-left: -4px;
  transition: all ease 0.5s;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px -3px 4px rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.09)
}

.card .content .category {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 600
}

.card .content .price {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #0d6efd
}

.card .content p {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}

.card:hover .content {
  bottom: 0%
}

.buttons button {
  border-radius: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  transition: all ease 0.3s
}

.content {
  height: 280px !important;
  padding: 10px;
}

.content .para {
  height: 100px !important;
}

hr {
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  width: 60%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 15px auto;
}

.d-flex {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 15px auto;
}

.fa-play-circle {
  padding-right: 4px;
  padding-top: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="image">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="image-column col-lg-3 col-md-6">
      <div class="card h-100 p-1 card-container">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h3>GABEL LOFFEL</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-img-wrapper ">
          <img src="assets\image_1.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
          <div class="content">
            <hr>
            <div class="para d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
              <p>Get out your <br> Lederhosen!</p>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center"> <i class="far fa-play-circle"></i> More </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="image-column col-lg-3 col-md-6">
      <div class="card h-100 p-1 card-container">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h3>GARY GARI</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-img-wrapper ">
          <img src="assets\image_2.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
          <div class="content">
            <hr>
            <div class="para d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
              <p>The delicious <br> headquarters for all <br> your ginger related <br> needs!</p>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center"> <i class="far fa-play-circle"></i> More </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-column col-lg-3 col-md-6">
      <div class="card h-100 p-1 card-container">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h3>IL PIATTO</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-img-wrapper ">
          <img src="assets\image_3.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
          <div class="content">
            <hr>
            <div class="para d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
              <p>Got wild finicky kids? <br> Head for Il Piatto for <br> kid-friendly Italian <br> Fun!
              </p>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center"> <i class="far fa-play-circle"></i> More </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-column col-lg-3 col-md-6">
      <div class="card h-100 p-1 card-container">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h3>PIERRE PLATTERS</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-img-wrapper ">
          <img src="assets\image_4.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
          <div class="content">
            <hr>
            <div class="para d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
              <p>Smart talks, Smart <br> eats!</p>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center"> <i class="far fa-play-circle"></i> More </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```